# Understanding Numpy datatypes

Tags: python, numpy

While reading PyCUDA documentation, I found out i did  not understand how this code works

```
numpy.getbuffer(numpy.intp(int(self.data)))
```

in theory it should return a pointer to float, while it receives self.data which is a pointer to an array of floats.

I am sure the question is simple, but after looking at more information about numpy.intp in books i did not find anything  that was of help.

Comment: Float? I see `int` and `intp`, which suggest integers.

Answer (score 0):

This is the source

https://documen.tician.de/pycuda/tutorial.html?highlight=getbuffer

```
class DoubleOpStruct:
    mem_size = 8 + numpy.intp(0).nbytes
    def __init__(self, array, struct_arr_ptr):
        self.data = cuda.to_device(array)
        self.shape, self.dtype = array.shape, array.dtype
        cuda.memcpy_htod(int(struct_arr_ptr), numpy.getbuffer(numpy.int32(array.size)))
        cuda.memcpy_htod(int(struct_arr_ptr) + 8, numpy.getbuffer(numpy.intp(int(self.data))))
    def __str__(self):
        return str(cuda.from_device(self.data, self.shape, self.dtype))

array1 = DoubleOpStruct(numpy.array([1, 2, 3], dtype=numpy.float32), struct_arr)
array2 = DoubleOpStruct(numpy.array([0, 4], dtype=numpy.float32), do2_ptr)
print("original arrays", array1, array2)
```

While the inputs to the class at `np.float32`, it isn't obvious what `cuda.to_device` returns.  It can't be an array, otherwise `int(self.data)` wouldn't work. (and contrary to my first read of your question `self.data` is not the data buffer of `self`.  It may be related but it isn't a buffer object).

So the expression must be doing something like:

```
>>> np.intp(2432353)
2432353
>>> np.getbuffer(np.intp(2432353))
<read-only buffer for 0xb74d1150, size -1, offset 0 at 0xb71dfba0>

>>> np.arange(4.).data
<read-write buffer for 0xb71dda98, size 32, offset 0 at 0xb71df1c0>
```

`cuda.to_device` maybe generating a number like the 'data' value of `__array_interface__`:

```
>>> np.arange(4.).__array_interface__['data']
(148454560, False)
>>> np.arange(4.).__array_interface__['data'][0]
148454560
>>> np.getbuffer(np.intp(int(_)))
<read-only buffer for 0xb74d1150, size -1, offset 0 at 0xb3a0c800>
```

(as a side note, `np.getbuffer` does not exist in Py3 versions of `numpy`).

In any case I don't see any datatype games here.

Comment: Yes, thank you, that is the source. Regarding `cuda.to_device(array)`,as far as i understand it allocates the array in the device and returns a pointer to its memory direction. What I still do not understand is why it is necessary to do the `intp(int())` thing, and not just `get.buffer` (or `memoryview` if you are using python 3).